# Excel formula to find lowest value above a given number and return the column name

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to write an Excel formula that will look at 5 columns of data (for example, labeled SEL1, SEL2, SEL3, SEL4, and SEL5) and return the column name of the lowest column with a value above a 0.80.

For example,

```
| SEL1 | SEL2 | SEL3 | SEL4 | SEL5 |
|------+------+------+------+------|
| 0.68 | 0.81 | 0.84 | 0.92 | 0.95 |
```

In this case, I'd want it to identify SEL2.

So far I have =INDEX(A$1:E$1,MATCH(MIN(A2:E2),A2:E2,0)) - it's returning SEL 1 because it's only looking at the minimum, not the minimum above a 0.80

Comment: Gonna need a `Match` in there somewhere. What do you have already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the array formula:

```
=INDEX(A1:E1,MATCH(MIN(IF(A2:E2>0.8,A2:E2)),A2:E2))
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: @Ryan  The little *Min(If())* is really powerful!.........using it you can take a table of numbers, remove duplicates and sort the left-overs, all in one swell foop!

Comment: Amazing, very good answer!